# Longing for solution to simple differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Well, it has happened again.

I have attempted to convert a mixed equation, and a simple one at that into a differential equation to solve.

I started out with

$\frac{dh}{d\rho'} + \frac{h}{\rho'} + \int \frac{h}{\rho'^2} d\rho' - \int \frac{m^2}{\rho'^2} d\rho' = \frac{1}{\rho'}$

Converted it to

$\frac{d^2h}{d\rho'^2} + \frac{1}{\rho'}\frac{dh}{d\rho'} - \frac{m^2}{\rho'^2} = -\frac{1}{\rho'^2}$

and finally to

$\frac{d^2h}{d\rho'^2} + \frac{1}{\rho'}\frac{dh}{d\rho'}  = \frac{m^2 -1}{\rho'^2}$

I think the guess for what the solution should sort of feel like if there was a $0$ on the right-hand side is to have something with a natural log but I don't know how to solve this full thing.

Comment: Did you try the method of Frobenius?

Comment: Not yet, I am hoping it wouldn't have to come to using that technique. I am hoping there is another way.

Comment: I think the usual idea is to solve the homogeneous part and then try to do something about the inhomogeneity by positing a polynomial and substituting it into the equation, and then going from there which is what I am trying at the moment. Then the full solution is the sum of the parts.

Comment: This might even be called method of undetermined coefficients but its been a while